# How to create copy of a Excel file without opening

Tags: vb.net, excel

What is the command to create a copy of an Excel file without opening it using [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

Answer (score 3):

File.Copy

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Let's keep it VB-centric: `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile()`

Answer (score 0):

The parm 'true' in the copy method says to overwrite any existing file so it doesn't bomb out.

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim originalFile As String = "c:\work\myExcelFile.xls"
        Dim copyOfOriginalFile As String = "c:\work\myExcelFileCopy.xls"

        If File.Exists(originalFile) Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(originalFile, copyOfOriginalFile, True) 
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist", originalFile)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If System.IO.File.Exists("Directory1" & "File.xlsx") Then
   My.Computer.File.System.CopyFile("Directory1" & "File.xlsx", 
                                     "Directory2" & "File.xlsx", True)
End If
```

Comment: Explain it in detail please.

Comment: What does this code do? How can it be used to solve the problem?